# How do I print out all items of a multi-dimensional array with custom markup?

Tags: php, loops, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array similar to this:

```
(
  [0] (
    title: 'First Group'
    type: 'group'
    children: (
      [0] (
        title: 'Inner Group'
        type: 'group'
        children: (
          [0] (
            title: 'Deep image'
            type: 'image'
          )
          [1] (
            title: 'Another deep image'
            type: 'image'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  [1] (
    title: 'Root depth image'
    type: 'image'
  )
)
```

I want to be able to work my way through this array and all it's children (this array could be infinitely recursive) to print/echo the content out to the browser.

The issue I have is being able to specify certain markup (and even perform conditionals on each item) for the different types of items.

*Eg. Print out each image's title only if it matches a regular expression, etc.*

The only method I can understand that will recursively sort through an array has to be a method/function that calls itself whenever children are found, but it seems that I will not be able to perform the conditionals if this is the case.

If a loop process (not using a function) exists, this would probably be the most suitable option, therefore at each child, I can perform any required conditions per-item.
I have tried with **while** and **foreach** loops but to no avail.

**NB:** I have compiled this array from two source arrays that weren't recursive, and could use these arrays that have related keys, if that helps the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If function getting over-complex you need a handler to do the job along with the recursive function.

```
function walk($array, $handler)
{
  foreach($array as $obj) {
      if(is_array($obj['children'])) {
        walk($obj['children'], $handler); //RECURSION
      } else {
        $handler($obj);
      }
   }
}
```

then write your handler function, regexp or whatever job its supposed to for each array element of type 'image'

```
function array_handler ($single_array){
         #Do some regexp or more complex job here.
     print $single_array['url']."<br/>";
}
```

and when you have to call,

```
walk ($myarray, 'array_handler');
```

basically we defined a new method called walk which act like foreach and while but the codeblock will be executed by the handler for each element.

Complete code,

```
<?php
$myarray = array( array (
           "title" => 'First Group',
           "type" => 'group',
           "children" => array (
                   array ("title" => 'Inner Group',
                        "type" => "group",
                    "children" => array (
                                   array (
                           "title" => "Deep Image",
                                   "type" => 'image',
                           "url" => "image.jpg"
                               ),
                               array (
                                   "title" => 'Another Deep Image',
                               "type" => 'image',
                           "url" => "image2.jpg"    
                               )
                    )      
                )

               )
            ),
                 array (
              "title" => 'Root Deep Image',
              "type" => 'image',
                      "url" => "image.jpg"
         )
        );




function walk($array, $handler)
{
  foreach($array as $obj) {
      if(is_array($obj['children'])) {
          walk($obj['children'], $handler); //RECURSION
      } else {
    $handler($obj);
      }
   }

}

function array_handler ($single_array){
     print $single_array['url']."<br/>";
}

walk ($myarray, 'array_handler');

?>
```

Comment: and have the walk method as common module available in your code and use it everywhere like you use foreach/while

Comment: Thank you this concept is exactly what I am after. I have actually extended this to allow strings with placeholders, orcustom functions, depending on what is required on a per-item basis

Answer (score 1):

You can only solve this problem recursively, as the input size is undefined.

That being said, you could try something like this:

```
 $regexp_map = array(
     'group' => 'some regexp',
     'image' => 'some other regexp'
 );

function walk($array) {
   $output = '';
   foreach($array as $obj) {
      if(is_array($obj['children'])) {
          $output .= walk($value['children']); //RECURSION
      } else {
          $regexp = $regexp_map[$obj['type']];
          if(preg_match($regexp, $obj['title'])) 
             $output .= $obj['title'];
      }
   }
   return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Although, regular expressions are just an example of how I want to be able to manipulation the data unfortunately, so I could see this function getting over-complex to allow the many different avenues of manipulation I require.